# IBM Worklight 6.1 - Google Map integration in a Windows Phone 8 app

Tags: google-maps, windows-phone-8, ibm-mobilefirst

Does IBM Worklight 6.1 supports Google Maps for Windows Phone 8?
If yes, then how to integrate it in my project? (any sample if possible)

Comment: You should use bing map [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207045%28v=vs.105%29.aspx] is documentation that describe how to use bing map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Why not do some googling on your own?
2. The question is not whether Worklight support it, but if Windows Phone 8 support it.

I've followed this guide (in the context of a Worklight app) and it worked for me:

- [Cross Platform Geolocation Mobile App in Windows Phone 8 and Android using Apache](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/showarticle.aspx?ID=953http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.1.0/cordova_geolocation_geolocation.md.html#Geolocation)

Also read the following:

- [Cordova Geolocation API](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.1.0/cordova_geolocation_geolocation.md.html#Geolocation)
- [Google Maps JavaScript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/)
- [Google Maps Getting Started](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial)

Here's a sample project in Worklight 6.1: [Google Maps using Cordova in Windows Phone 8](https://www.dropbox.com/s/g79c86v584qo468/wp8_maps.zip)

After you build the project in Eclipse and opening it in Visual Studio 2012, make sure to open the `WMAppManifest.xml` file and verify the following required capabilities are checked: `ID_CAP_LOCATION`, `ID_CAP_MAP`.

Screen shot from Windows Phone 8 Emulator:
[image]